# change default printing settings

Tags: printing, settings, default

Is there any way to change the default printing settings in the dialog box?

For instance, I would like the paper format to be always `A4`. Now it always appears as `US letter` by default and I have to change it each time.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?  But you can do that from the printer properties page.

Comment: 12.04. I went to all settings -> printers but there wasn't anything about this. Did I look in the wrong place? I don't see anything else about printing in the settings

Comment: @RickyRobinson did it work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use Cups administration page. You can access it by opening `http://localhost:631` in your web browser.

Then select Administration -> Manage Printers

[image]

Select your printer and then, on the "Administration" dropbox choose "Set Default options". Change the default settings and finally press "Set default options". If it asks you the username/password use the same combination you use to login.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this thing was extremely well hidden. Thanks!

Comment: @Salem I get "Unauthorized", and it asks me to enter username and password with no form fields.

Comment: You need to add your username to the lpadmin group.

Comment: Nice job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Via Ubuntu settings

On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS the settings can **normally** be set via

Settings --> Printers -->
[image: PrintingOptionsDropdown]

But they don't always seem to take effect or perhaps there is another configuration conflicting which takes precedence.

### Via CUPS server

Salem in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/296677/258256) describes how to access the [CUPS server via web-browser](http://localhost:631/admin).

This server can also be accessed under

Settings --> Printers -->  Select Additional printer settings
[image: AdditionalPrinterSettings]

A GUInterface of the connection to the local host server will appear
[image]

Right click on the printer of interest and select properties, etc, etc..